# Is there a locally limited subscription option for profile search on Careers?

Tags: support, jobs, localization, pricing

We are looking to hire in Shanghai, China.

$1000 USD for a month of access to the resume database may be a good deal if you are hiring globally or in the US or Europe, but Careers has just 350 profiles from Shanghai, and less than 100 tagged Java.

Is it possible to get a subscription to a locally limited subset, priced in accordance to the size of that subset?

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry Thilo, we don't have that option right now, but we have discussed pricing structures like that before.

What we do have is our unconditional money back guarantee. We don't want your money unless you're amazingly happy with what you purchased. So if you do decide to buy a month and are unsatisfied for any reason we will issue you a refund. No questions asked. (Well we might ask the reason so we know how to improve our offering, but if you answer that with "the sky was blue today" you still get the refund.)

Comment: That sounds fair (weird but fair). I'll think about this, with the criterion for "amazingly happy" being "we found at least one person that we liked enough to make an offer".